# Spring Data JPA-Retrieve generated id when using native sql insert

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have the following native sql insert query when using Spring Data JPA:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "insert into marker(name, event_id, position, tag_ids, gmt_create, gmt_modified)" +
            " values(?#{#m.name}, ?#{#m.eventId}, ST_GeomFromText(?#{#m.position})" +
            ", ?#{#m.tagIds}, ?#{#m.gmtCreate}, ?#{#m.gmtModified})"
            , nativeQuery = true)
    Marker save(@Param(value = "m") Marker marker);
```

The question is how to get the auto generated id? Thank you so much!

Comment: Well I give up. I will generate the ID for myself

Comment: You should retrieve it through the instance `marker' to insert. Before you insert `marker` the `id` is null, but after you have done the insert the entity marker which you have inserted should have been updated with the Id. Then you can access it.   

`Marker marker = new Marker(); //set marker data but with id null
repository.save(marker);
//Then marker.getId() is not null
Long id = market.getId();`

Have you tried?

Comment: yes, the save method will insert the id for me but I want to custom the sql at the same time.